# javascript Check type of attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the type of result by query for example

```
var titles = $(this).attr('name');
```

In case that the name is: `["str1", "str2"]`, I want to identify that the titles is a list/array. Is it possible and how can I know if it is a string or array, and in case that it is array to get each value from the array.

Comment: Are you sure that's the name of your HTML element? Either way, you could use `JSON.parse` wrapped in a `try/catch` to check if the value is at least valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The value of an attribute is **always** a string, never an array. If you then want to interpret that string as something else, you need to check that it fits the format you expect (perhaps with a regular expression) and parse/convert it to that format.

In your case, for instance, you might see if it's valid JSON (although `["str1", "str2"]` is a **very** unusual value for the `name` attribute of an element):

```
var titles = $(this).attr("name");
var parsed = null;
try {
    parsed = JSON.parse(titles);
}
catch (e) {
}
// Here, if `parsed` is not `null`, it was valid JSON and is the array
```

Comment: Just to note that `.attr()` is always a string but jquery's `.data()` infers the type in some cases eg ("2" === number === 2) - but not in the case of an array, it just sees it as a string https://jsfiddle.net/3yq9g561/

Answer (score 0):

After parsing the content of `$(this).attr('name')`. ([It's always a string](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1))

In order to check if the object is an array you can:

```
Array.isArray([1, 2, 3]);  //TRUE
Array.isArray("Some title");  //False
```